# React Native #Networking.sendRequest got 9 arguments, expected 8

Tags: android, react-native

When I try to fetch data at ReactNative version 0.44.0 it works on iOS but gets this error message on Android:

```
Networking.sendRequest got 9 arguments, expected 8
```

The code for both iOS and Android is:

```
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
         return responseJson.movies;
    })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: I do not think that you should put a return inside `componentDidMount` try removing it and see if it makes a difference

Comment: I remove all return in `componentDidMount` but I get same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Each version of react-native is matched with a specific Expo SDK version: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/sdk/index.html#sdk-version

As I'm using Expo SDK Version 18.0.0, I've just updated sdkVersion to 18.0.0 in app/exp.json as shown below.

```
{
   "expo": {
    "name": "Your App Name",
    "icon": "./path/to/your/app-icon.png",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "slug": "your-app-slug",
    "sdkVersion": "18.0.0",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
    }
   }
 }
```

It worked for me.

If you still get the error please refer these: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/269